# Admin account only shows Profile and Dashboard with no activity

Tags: wp-admin, admin, admin-menu

I received login credentials from the person that maintains my company's website. When I login, there is virtually no information on it. I can only access the dashboard which has no activity on it.

Why is this?

Do some websites host files in a separate location and just use wordpress to handle the display (so no posts would ever be shown on the wordpress admin page)? If so, what should I ask for to gain access to the admin page that they actually use?

Or did the person give me a locked down user account that doesn't have access to these files?

Below are screenshots of what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an admin account, this looks like a basic subscriber or customer account.

They are probably hesitant to give you full admin access because you could potentially break things.  I run into this all the time with our marketing department.  But if this is your website and you want full access they should be able to provide it.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I suspected. Is asking for full admin access the correct terminology? Or is there a way to just get access to view the entire account, but only view things? Like full admin access, but only read capabilities.

Comment: I would just ask them to switch your user role to "Administrator".  Then you will be able to login with the same username/password but see everything.

Comment: Also, ask them why they're so many versions behind in WP - you're still at 4.8.9 while the current version is 5.4.1.